# Android rendering issues Marshmallow 6.0

Tags: android, android-6.0-marshmallow

There seems to be some rendering problems when using phone Moto G3 with Marshmallow 6.0. With Lollipop it works fine.

I'm using these setting in the manifest

```
android:minSdkVersion="14"
android:targetSdkVersion="21"
```

When debugging with Android studio preview screens set to API 23 I cant find any rendering issues.

Any ideas how to solve this?

Here is the layout that has issues

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"

android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:minWidth="330dp"
android:minHeight="300dp"
android:background="@color/agrey"
android:gravity="center" >

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/etNameny"
    android:layout_width="180dp"
    android:layout_height="40dp"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="45dp"
    android:background="@drawable/myborderlist"
    android:ems="5"

    android:maxLength="10"
    android:paddingLeft="5dp"
    android:singleLine="true"
    android:textColor="@color/black"
    android:textSize="25dp" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/etDate1ny"
    android:layout_width="180dp"
    android:layout_height="40dp"
    android:background="@drawable/myborderlist"
    android:editable="false"
    android:ems="5"
    android:inputType="date|none"
    android:maxLength="10"
    android:onClick="setDate"
    android:paddingLeft="5dp"
    android:singleLine="true"
    android:textAlignment="center"
    android:textColor="@color/black"
    android:textSize="25dp"
    android:layout_above="@+id/trName"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/trName"
    android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/trName">
</Button>

<EditText

    android:id="@+id/inkl1ny"
    android:layout_width="180dp"
    android:layout_height="40dp"
    android:background="@drawable/myborderlist"
    android:ems="5"
    android:maxLength="10"
    android:paddingLeft="5dp"
    android:singleLine="true"
    android:textColor="@color/black"
    android:textSize="25dp"
    android:layout_below="@+id/momsprocent11ny"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/momsprocent11ny"
    android:layout_alignStart="@+id/momsprocent11ny"
    android:inputType="numberDecimal" />

<EditText

    android:id="@+id/momsprocent11ny"
    android:layout_width="180dp"
    android:layout_height="40dp"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/etNameny"
    android:layout_below="@+id/etNameny"
    android:background="@drawable/myborderlist"
    android:ems="5"

    android:inputType="numberDecimal"

    android:paddingLeft="5dp"
    android:singleLine="true"
    android:textColor="@color/black"
    android:textSize="25dp" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/trName"
    android:layout_width="170dp"
    android:layout_height="40dp"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/bClear1"
    android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/etNameny"
    android:maxLength="10"
    android:singleLine="false"
    android:text="@string/tbName"
    android:textColor="@color/black"
    android:textSize="15dp"
    android:layout_above="@+id/momsprocent11ny" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/trDateCopy"
    android:layout_width="170dp"
    android:layout_height="40dp"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/momsprocent11ny"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/trName"
    android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/etDate1ny"
    android:maxLength="10"
    android:singleLine="true"
    android:text="@string/tbVatProcent"
    android:textColor="@color/black"
    android:textSize="14dp" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/tvAlv141"
    android:layout_width="150dp"
    android:layout_height="40dp"
    android:layout_above="@+id/bClear1"
    android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/etDate1ny"
    android:maxLength="6"
    android:singleLine="true"
    android:text="@string/tbSum"
    android:textColor="@color/black"
    android:textSize="14dp"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/trDateCopy" />



<Button
    android:id="@+id/bClear1"
    android:layout_width="90dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_below="@+id/inkl1ny"
    android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="36dp"
    android:background="@drawable/myborderlist"
    android:maxLength="6"
    android:text="@string/akCancel" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/buttonMain"
    android:layout_width="90dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/bAdd1"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/bAdd1"
    android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/bClear1"
    android:background="@drawable/myborderlist"
    android:maxLength="6"
    android:text="@string/akClear" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/bAdd1"
    android:layout_width="90dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@drawable/myborderlist"
    android:maxLength="6"
    android:text="@string/akAdd"
    android:layout_alignTop="@+id/bClear1"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/buttonMain"
    android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/buttonMain" />


</RelativeLayout>
```

Here follows the difference between Lollipop and Marshmallow

[image]

[image]

Comment: You should read documentation to learn how to update Gradle settings. Upgrade Gradle to API 23 probably can't solve rendering issues. Codes should be updated as well.

Comment: I edited the question. I asked wrong kind of question

Comment: Still you have to specify which part of layout has rendering problems, and show you layout XML codes. Also, Android Studio will hint which part of codes require updates to fit API 23.

Comment: I cant get the hints because I have this app and a user uses it on two phones. One with Marshmallow has the issues. The problem is that I haven't got any phone with Marshmallow so I can test it. I added the xml.

Comment: I added som texts in the question where I quote the user

Comment: Still not able to understand your issue, if there is an issue in layout showing in the screen then put the screen shots of both 5.0 and 6.0 so one can identify rendering issue.

Comment: It's better to show the screenshots, as suggested by @SilvansSolanki

Comment: Ok, I will ask the user to send me a screenshot

Comment: Added the screenshots

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that Marshmallow 6.0 has some issues when rendering a little bit of a messed up code as I had in the xml layout. I changed to Linear layout and made
the layout with a more strikt and clean code.

Now it works. Don't make messy codes, it will give rendering issues!

Answer (score 0):

Change Compile version to 23 and targetsdkversion to 23

```
compileSdkVersion 23
targetSdkVersion 23
```

Hope this will help you.

Comment: I edited the question. I asked wrong kind of question